# Swagger UI is blank or empty when i try t connect it to kong.yaml

Tags: docker, docker-compose, swagger, swagger-ui, kong

This is the swagger of port `8099` [swagger of 8099](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBFOM.png) then after i connect it to kong [kong swagger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lR00J.png) the tab name is changing to `Swagger UI` that means its working but its empty. Any Solution?

```
//kong.yaml for swagger
_format_version: "2.1"
_transform: true

services:

#  ------ Swagger port -------
- host: host.docker.internal
  port: 8099
  name: swagger-service
  path: /swagger-ui/index.html
  routes:
  - name: swagger-service
    paths:
    - /swagger
    strip_path: true
```

After i enter the port `http://localhost:8000/swagger` this will show

```
kong              | 172.24.0.1 - - [24/May/2022:07:48:11 +0000] "GET /favicon-16x16.png HTTP/1.1" 404 48 "http://localhost:8000/swagger" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.64 Safari/537.36 Edg/101.0.1210.53"
```

Comment: I have to say I have never worked with kong before, but we do use Traefik. In our case, it was the .net core provider for swagger. But whenever you change the  "base" path of your swagger host from / to /swagger/ for instance, you need to let the swagger configuration know it fetches the CSS and other resources from /swagger/things-to-fetch.css instead from /things-to-fetch.css. This could be the issue you are seeing.

Comment: https://medium.com/@peterkimnyc/url-rewriting-in-kong-b887d65ca072 this can help